# Regex can accept 12 numerics but the first character has to have an X or a number

Tags: regex

The first character to be X or a number, the rest 11 numbers.

ex:

```
898765432108 or 
X27654321987
```

I though of:  `^[x-X][0-9]{11}$`

What would be the solution?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, you should accept one.

Comment: Java programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x-X` is not valid regular expression. Do this

```
^[xX\d]\d{11}$
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/k6HPIY/2)

**Note**

You cannot have `[x-X]` you will get an error saying 'range out of order' as [quackenator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6776262/quackenator) mentioned Uppercase comes first in ASCII table so it is an invalid order.

> When specifying a range of characters, such as [a-Z] (i.e. lowercase a
>   to upper-case z), the computer's locale settings determine the
>   contents by the numeric ordering of the character encoding.

**Order matters when specifying a range.**

Comment: I think the order may matter here. With `X-x` being a valid range, but `x-X` being invalid. Uppercase comes first in ASCII table

Comment: @quackenator yup!

Comment: Ah, uppercase is first.

Comment: @EduardoDennis :p beat me to the punch.

Comment: @quackenator I gave you a mention :)

Answer (score 5):

You regex `^[x-X][0-9]{11}$` will allow whole ASCII range from `x` to `X`, but since `X` comes before `x` this range is **out of order**. Better use `[xX]` to avoid exceptions by programming language.

> The first character to be X or a number.

For that first character should be defined by character class having `\d` i.e number range `0-9`, `x` and `X`.

Correct regex should be: `^[\dxX]\d{11}$` where `\d` denotes range `0-9`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0rsP1L/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try `^[xX\d]\d{11}$` this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex [x-X] doesn't actually make any sense, you could have either written or [xX] or compare by ignoring case sensitivity as I did below.

And [x-X][0-9]{11} will not match patterns starting with a number as you haven't included a number check in first case, so it has to be either [xX0-9] or [xX\d] or as written below to exclude case sensitivity.

```
import re
st = "X27654321987"
print bool(re.match(r"^[X0-9]\d{11}$", st, re.U|re.I))
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.